# How do I create an element with attributes out of a property

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am using xml's serialization in .net. I have a property called tier:

```
public string tier { get; set; }
```

The end result I want to obtain when the object is serialized is:

```
<settings>
    //Where the value is the value of the tier property
    <setting name="tier" value="2" /> 
</settings>
```

What xml serialization attributes can be used to accomplish this with that one property?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with serialization attributes. Your object have any other properties? Those properties should also go as `setting` elements?

Comment: @programmer93 that will crate attribute `tier="2"`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I thought that's what he wanted??

Comment: Look at XmlAttributeAttribute.

Comment: Yes, my "installfile" object does have other properties, but none of which will go into this Settings element I am trying to create.

Comment: Will I have to use a dictionary instead of a simple string to hold the tier value...and serialize that to get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `XmlSerializer` does not directly support this scenario. It could handle:

```
<foo><tier>2</tier></foo>
```

or

```
<foo tier="2"/>
```

But not what you want, unless you twist the model greatly out of shape.

Would it be possible to use LINQ-to-XML?

```
var setting = new Setting { tier = "2" };

var xml = new XElement("settings", new XElement("setting",
    new XAttribute("tier", setting.tier)));
```

Not quite automated serialization, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I was thinking of some restructuring instead. Instead of having a simple string property, i was thinking of wrapping it in a "Settings" class with two members in this class..."name" and "value" and then apply the [xmlattribute] to those members and [xmlelement] to the actual class.

Any thoughts on this approach?